# Need help stopping functions in corona

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to stop 3 animations in my function when it reaches a certain point and then have a message display "Animations Stopped".

How would I do this? I know about `display.NewText()` but how would I go about stopping the animations and getting the message to pop up at the same time?

Here is the function I'm trying to stop.

```
WIDTH = display.contentWidth
HEIGHT = display.contentHeight
--displays background
local s = display.newImageRect("space.png" ,1136, 640)
s.x = 900/2
s.y = 500/2

--display main ship
local r = display.newImageRect("ship.png", 70, 70)
r.x = 20
r.y = 450

local minions = {}

function createMinions()
    local x = 40
local y = 120
for n = 1, 20 do -- displays 20 minions
    local minion = display.newImageRect("minion.png", 50, 50)
    minion.x = x
    minion.y = y

    minions[n] = minion
    x = x + 60  -- next enemy will be to the right
    if x >= WIDTH then  -- start a new row if necessary
        y = y + 60 -- seperation between minions
        x = 40
        end
    end
end

 --display mothership
 m = display.newImageRect("mothership.png", 150, 150)
 m.x = 160
 m.y = 10

function nextFrame() 
-- begins movements of main ship to right
r.x = r.x + 5 
if r.x > 350 then
    r.x = -100
end
-- begins movement of minions to the left
    for i = 1, 20 do
        local minion = minions[i]
        minion.x = minion.x - 8
        if minion.x < -100 then
            minion.x = 400
        end
    end
--begins movement of mothership towards small ship
    m.y = m.y + 10
    if m.y > 460 then
        m.y = -100
    end
    --stops all animations
    if m.y > 450 then
        --r.x = r.x + 0
        --m.y = m.y + 0
        --minion.x = minion.x + 0
        local s = true
        --displays game over text
        s = display.newText("Game Over", WIDTH/2, 400, native, 30)

    end

end
createMinions()

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", nextFrame )

--hides status bar
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
```

Comment: What do you mean you are trying to "stop" it? Just stop calling it? You need to show us where you are calling it for us to tell you how to stop it.

Comment: Alright just posted the entire script from corona. I just want all the objects in my animation to stop as soon as m.y > 450 and display the game over sign

Comment: Just wrap it all in ´if(m.y < 450) then YOURCODE end´

Comment: Ah ok. But how would I get the text to appear only when all the objects have stopped? Because right now it's there from the start of the animation.

Comment: `if(m.y < 450) then YOURCODE else DISPLAYTEXTCODE end` - But it sounds like you are designing this wrong. You should look into listeners and transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make it very short -

This is the code specific to your problem.

```
if(m.y < 450) then YOURCODE else DISPLAYTEXTCODE end
```

For future I suggest people to look at:

[Corona Docs: API > Libraries > Transition > To](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html) - To move display objects.

and

[Corona Docs: APi > Types > EventListener > addEventListener](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/EventListener/addEventListener.html) - To trigger code based on events.